# ListView.getCheckedItemCount() doesn't change value after setItemChecked

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a ListView allowing multiple selection configured with an `ArrayAdapter`, everything works fine but when I try to set to false some selected items the `getCheckedItemCount` value doesn't change

Just to replicate the behavior I unselect all items using the code shown below and the printed value is the same before and after the `getCheckedItemCount` call

Why?

```
for (MyObject post : list) {
    int position = photoAdapter.getPosition(post);
    System.out.println("count before " + photoListView.getCheckedItemCount());
    photoListView.setItemChecked(position, false);
    System.out.println("count after " + photoListView.getCheckedItemCount());
}
```

Obviously to unselect all items we must call `clearChoices()` but the code above is used only to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dafi i am not sure this is working in your case but below solution give me right count. The easiest solution is to clear the checked count manually.You just try it.

```
this.markersList.clearChoices();
for(int i = 0; i < this.markersList.getCount(); i++)
{        
this.markersList.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Try out this solution.

Comment: Thanks, I know it but I would understand why setting to false doesn't update The count. Is this a bug?

Comment: @dafi let me try this with false value.